# What is it called when a snake is showing its head when angry?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the apt word to be used when a snake has its head looking straight towards us and shows its tongue outside vociferously, *probably when it is about to bite*?

As user @J.R. suggested "mesmerizes" seems to be somewhat near. But I need something more than that, especially when like the snake is in a attempting position to bite someone.

Comment: Run...........!

Comment: I think you should provide a litte more context by editing your question. For a cobra, I believe that's called a _threatening_ position. But there are also instances in literature where a snake _mesmerizes_ its prey, so such a snake could be _undulating_ as well. This depends on if we are watching a snake charmer, or if we are in danger of getting bit.

Comment: mesmerizes seems to be somewhat near..but i need something more than that...especially when its in a bad mood to bite someone...

Comment: Possibly *reared*.

Comment: @Lucky: notice I said "by editing your question." A comment is not an edit; it forces everyone else to read through this discussion to get a clarification you probably should have provided in the first place.

Comment: Most snakes must be *coiled* to a degree in order to strike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is *hooded*.

Comment: Not all snakes are _hooded_, it is specific to [cobras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra).

Comment: You're right. Though I believe the original poster has a picture in mind of a hooded snake. So it seems.

Answer (score 2):

There is a *phrase* which suits the mentioned scenario: "*ready to strike*". The complete phrase(literary) goes like this

> ......coiled and ready to strike.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *rear up*:

> The snake *reared up*, ready to strike.

Based on: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reared

> 7.
>   (of a person) to start up in angry excitement, hot resentment, or the like (usually followed by up).

Comment: Thanks anyway but it was already suggested by tylerharms in his comments. :) Also the (of a person) makes me think its only for people and not animals. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I missed it in the comments. "Reared up" was my first thought and I've only read/heard it used for animals; see 6. to rise on the hind legs, as a horse or other animal. Snakes are legless, but it's the same movement.